# Show $\cosh([0,\infty))=[1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have been stuck at this problem for a long time and i cannot figure out a solution.
Prove $\cosh([0,\infty))=[1,\infty)$
**Hint:** Try to show $\cosh(x)\rightarrow \infty$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$ and the sentence: For a continuously function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on a closed limited interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ will the codomain contain all numbers between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Comment: can you solve cosh(x)=1?

Comment: Yes, $cosh(0)=\dfrac{e^0+e^{-0}}{2}=1$

Comment: Try writing the definition of $\cosh$, and plugging in values for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You could show, that $\cosh$ is strictly increasing (in $[0,\infty)$) by looking at it's derivative.
Furthermore show that it is unbound and use Continuity and the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

- $\cosh(x)$ is a continuous function.
- $\cosh(x)=\dfrac{z+z^{-1}}2$ with $z=e^x>0.$
- in the positive $z$, $z+z^{-1}\ge2$ because $\dfrac{(z-1)^2}z\ge0$. The bound is tight because $1+1^{-1}=2.$
- $e^x$ is unbounded (take $x\ge n$ and $e^x>e\cdot e\cdots e$), and $2\cosh(x)>e^x.$

So $\cosh(x)$ covers all values from $1$ inclusive to $\infty$.